# Pause animation on hover Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, hover, jquery-animate

I have a timer which I want to pause when hovered and I want it to resume when the mouse leaves.
With jquery I achieved that, but every time the mouse leaves the element it doesn't resume smoothly and if I hover it several times, sometimes it crashes completely.

Here's the code

HTML

```
 <div class="progressBar">
 <div class="progressImg timer-blue" >
     <img src="https://labs.jellycode.pt/websites/PintoBrasil/wp-content/themes/JELLYCODE/images/timer-blue.png">
 </div>
 <div class="progressImg">
     <img src="https://labs.jellycode.pt/websites/PintoBrasil/wp-content/themes/JELLYCODE/images/timer-white.png">
 </div>
    </div>
```

JQUERY

```
var $progressBar = $('.timer-blue');

    function runIt() {
        $progressBar.animate({
            width: "50px",
        }, 5000, function() {
            $progressBar.css("width", "0")
            runIt();
        });
        $('.progressBar').hover(function() {
            $('.timer-blue').stop();
        }, function() {
            runIt();
        });
    }

    runIt();
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ebvd9saf/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/ebvd9saf/3/). It looks to me like it's dont have the delay.

```
var $progressBar = $('.timer-blue');

function runIt() {
    $progressBar.animate({
        width: "50px",
    }, 5000, function() {
        $progressBar.css("width", "0")
        runIt();
    });
}


    $('.progressBar').hover(function() {
        $('.timer-blue').clearQueue();
        $('.timer-blue').stop();
    }, function() {
        runIt();
    });
runIt();
```

Comment: hey thanks. Still, if i hover the element a lot of times it still freezes my site for a while, I don't know if it's a problem on my side.

Comment: I have tried everything i can to make it crash and so far i Cant make it crash

Comment: It may be something on my site then, anyway I  managed to get around the problem, I did the timer differently. Really appreciate all your help, thanks ;)